# Why isnt my executable compiling?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So right now, I have two executables within one package. I had created the first executable a few days back. But after creating the second executable and using the `catkin_make` command, only the first program gets compiled and not the second. What am I doing wrong? Is it because of the two executables within one package? Also, if I type `rosrun package executable2`, I get the following error - "Couldn't find executable names executable2"

My Cmake file -

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(first_package)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp geometry_msgs)
catkin_package()
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(hello hello.cpp pubvel pubvel.cpp)
target_link_libraries(hello ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

I am pretty sure the error is due to the `add_executable` part of my CMakeLists.txt. hello.cpp is the first executable whereas pubvel.cpp is the second executable.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312616/why-isnt-my-executable-compiling?/) by [TristanNoctis](https://answers.ros.org/users/39423/tristannoctis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2019-01-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-01-13**:
Can you update your question will your CMakeLists.txt file, and the details of the source files that are needed to compile each executable. We can't help you if we don't know how your workspace is setup.

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2019-01-13**:
We need to see your CMakeLists.txt. As to your last sentence, have you sourced your catkin_ws and restarted the terminal?

**Comment by [TristanNoctis](https://answers.ros.org/users/39423/tristannoctis/) on 2019-01-13**:
Hey I have updated my CMakeLists.txt. Can you please check?

**Comment by [TristanNoctis](https://answers.ros.org/users/39423/tristannoctis/) on 2019-01-13**:
This is my other workspace that I have created other than the 'catkin_ws'. And yes I have sourced it before using the catkin_make

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2019-01-13**:
Try the first part of my answer.

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2019-01-13**:
Also try adding new `add_executable` and `target_link_libraries` for pubvel instead of merging them into one (I am not sure if you can do what you are doing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to add appropriate CMake macros at the end of your `CMakeLists.txt` file:

At the very bottom add these two lines for each executable:

1. `add_executable(node_name src/file_name.cpp)`
2. `target_link_libraries(node_name ${catkin_LIBRARIES})`

This will tell catkin to build and install the executable in your `devel/lib/package_name` directory.

If none of the above works I am presuming there's something wrong with your ROS install. Providing your `CMakeLists.txt` file would be helpful.

EDIT: Update your `CMakeLists.txt` to:

```
add_executable(hello src/hello.cpp
target_link_libraries(hello ${catkin_LIBRARIES}

add_executable(pubvel src/pubvel.cpp
target_link_libraries(pubvel ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
```

Ensure your src is stored in `~/your_ws/src/your_package/src` directory.

---

Originally posted by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) with karma: 120 on 2019-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-01-13**:
Although you're correct in the end that the problem was with the add_executable tags in CMakeLists.txt. You absolutely do not have to re-source your workspace every time you run catkin_make.

**Comment by [TristanNoctis](https://answers.ros.org/users/39423/tristannoctis/) on 2019-01-14**:
Your update to the CMakeLists.tst worked! Only problem now is that I have to source the setup.bash each time I open a new terminal.

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2019-01-14**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd, my apologies, I was meant to say everytime you build a new package, where a new devel and build folders are created!

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2019-01-14**:
@TristanNoctis, you don't, just follow the steps I added in part 1.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-01-14**:
@Hypomania no problem, could you update your answer so it doesn't include the part about sourcing the work space. It's quite confusing at the moment, as the first half doesn't answer the OPs question and is incorrect. The second half in great though.

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2019-01-14**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd, initially I thought his ws wasn't source. If it's not sourced it won't get recognized by bash (correct me if I am wrong), is that still irrelevant to the question?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-01-14**:
That's true, but the question was about compiling multiple binaries. The first binary was okay, then the problem appeared when they tried to compile a second binary. Plus the actual fault in this case was the CMakeLists.txt so that should be the focus of the answer.

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2019-01-15**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd, that makes sense, I will edit it out.